# Update table column based on CTE result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-update

I have the code shown below, and I want to update my original table to reflect the results of this query. I want each record's `Route_type` column to update with the corresponding value from the `Route_type` column in the query based on the code associated with each record. For instance, all records with `code=1` should have `Route_Type` updated to "Other" based on the query.

```
With Route_Number_CTE (Code,Year_and_Week, Route_Count) As
(
    Select 
        Code, Year_and_Week, Count(Route) AS Route_Count
    From 
        Deliveries
    Group by
        Code, Year_and_Week
)
select 
    d.Code, 
    min(r.Route_Count) As Min_Count,
    max(r.Route_Count) As Max_Count,
    (case
        When max(r.Route_Count) = 1 then 'One'
        When max(r.Route_Count) <= 3 AND min(r.Route_Count) > 1 then 'Three or less'
        When min(r.Route_Count) > 4 then 'Four or More'
        Else 'Other'
     End) As Route_Type
From 
    Deliveries as d
inner join 
    Route_Number_CTE as r on d.Code = r.Code
Group By 
    d.Code;
```

Query results:

```
Code  Min_Count  Max_Count   Route_Type
----------------------------------------
1     1          4           Other
2     1          2           Three or less
3     3          3           Three or less
```

Deliveries:

```
Code   Route   Route_Type
-------------------------
1      A
1      C
1      D
2      A
2      C    
2      B
3      A
3      C
3      D
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could use window functions and an updatable cte. This is simpler, and should be more efficient as it avoids the need for aggregation and joins:

```
with cte as (
    select route_type, max(cnt) over(partition by code) max_cnt
    from (
        select d.*, count(*) over(partition by code, year_and_week) cnt
        from deliveries d
    ) d
)
update cte
set route_type = case
    when max_cnt =  1 then 'One'
    when max_cnt <= 3 then 'Three or less'
    when max_cnt >  4 then 'Four or more'
end
```

Comment: @GMB...how do you validate your code?  Is there some online tool that can do this for you? I see a lot of questions that seem very interesting, but there is no 'CREATE TABLE...' and 'INSERT INTO...', etc, etc.  Do you type out all this code yourself and answer countless questions, or do you just look at the questions, and you automatically know what to do?  Don't you need the CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO?  Just curious.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by just creating a second CTE from the second Select statement and using an update query with the result.